# Counting elements in a list with different objects given a property

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, dynamic-cast

So i got this two classes and i want to count the number of FlowersGarden objects with the specie rose in my list:

```
class Garden {
private:
    string owner;
    double lenght, width;
public:
    Garden(string ow, double l, double w) {
        this->ownder = ow;
        this->lenght = l;
        this->width = w;
}

class FlowersGarden: public Garden {
private:
    string species;
public:
    FlowersGarden(string ow, double l, double w, string sp):Garden(ow, l, w) {
        this->species = sp;
}
    string GetSpecies()const {return species;};
};
```

main.cpp

```
Graden** list;
list = new Garden* [5];
list[0] = new Garden("asdas", 54, 57);
list[1] = new FlowersGarden("tyyty", 98, 87, "rose");
list[2] = new FlowersGarden("asdasd", 578, 212, "sadas");
list[3] = new Garden("uyiyui", 687, 212); 
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    if(dynamic_cast<FlowersGarden*>(list[i]))
        if(list[i]->GetSpecies() == "rose")
           count++;
```

That's only i can think of solving this problem and i'm getting this error: "class 'Garden' has no member named 'GetSpecies'" and i see why, but i don't know another way.

Comment: Your using C# grammar for C++ it seems like.

Comment: `GetSpecies()` instead `GetSpecie()`

Comment: That was a typo, but that wasn't the thing the was causing the problem.

Comment: Don't copy-type your code code, rather copy-paste and you won't get a typo.

Comment: By the way, I'd recommend using `std::count_if` with a lambda function instead of handrolling it.  e.g. `int count = std::count_if(list, list+4, [](const Garden* g) { if (auto fg = dynamic_cast<FlowersGarden*>(g)) return (fg->GetSpecies() == "rose"); else return false; });`

Comment: @CraigYoung I see, but still that wasn't why i got the error. I wrote the code that way, because it was in another language so i simplified it.

Comment: @DanielSchepler In the problem i counting isn't the only thing i was supose to do with the "rose" object so i didn't want to use STL.

Comment: You use `std::string` but neither `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `if(dynamic_cast<FlowersGarden*>(list[i]))`

This guard properly verifies the derived type is of type `FlowerGarden`. However, `list[0]->GetSpecies` is still using a pointer of type `Garden` which doesn't have the function you're trying to use.

You just need to keep the result of the cast and use it to call the function. For example:

```
if (FlowersGarden* result = dynamic_cast<FlowersGarden*>(list[i]))
{
    if (result->GetSpecies() == "rose")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** As @max66 points out in the comments. The code you posted appears to have a typo for the function the the `FlowersGarden` class, `GetSpecie` vs `GetSpecies`.

---

Edit:

I'm not sure what you're trying to do ultimately (regarding your class hierarchy) but I thought it would be apropos to point out `virtual` functions. If you're in a situation where there is a function that is applicable to ***all*** the derived classes then you shuld add it the the base class and make it `virtual`. By doing this the need to perform a `dynamic_cast` is unnecessary and dynamic dispatching will call the derived class implementation when called through a base class pointer.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual void print() const = 0; // Pure abstract function
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void print() const override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    base->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Derived
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/qcv6xs)</kbd>